# Facing redirection issues in custom module in magento 1.4.2.0

Tags: magento

i have set secure url in magento and also set use secure url in front end variable. it is working perfect in default magento modules, we have made custom module wich is redirecting to secure url by 302 redirection. i want to redirect it to as default magento works.

Please help in this regards.

Comment: you need to provide examples of what you have tried... what code do you already have that you want to insert the redirect?

Comment: it is resolved. i have an issue with ssl. its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

[smart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376830/smart), the OP, already self-answered the question.

Quote:

> it is resolved. i have an issue with ssl. its working fine now

<sub>Note: It's absolutely [OK to self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question. Please just post it as an real answer, but *not* in a question or comment. Posting as real answer helps to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear (avoids making other people wasting their time).</sub>

Comment: what was the problem? I'm facing the same

Comment: @Netismine: unfortunately the original poster [smart](http://stackoverflow.com/users/376830/smart) did not explain yet what exactly his issue with SSL was and how he solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add different "**frontName**" for `<admin>` and `<frontend>` routers in **config.xml** file of your module.

For example, you can see in the **config.xml** code below that admin and frontend routers have different name. Admin router name is **frontName**. Frontend router name is **frontName1**

```
<admin>
       <routers>
         <[ModuleName]>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>[NameSpace_ModuleName]</module>
                <frontName>[frontName]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[ModuleName]>
    </routers>
</admin>

<frontend>
       <routers>
         <[ModuleName]>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>[NameSpace_ModuleName]</module>
                <frontName>[frontName1]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[ModuleName]>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

**Source**: https://magecracker.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/why-magento-custom-module-frontend-url-is-forced-to-https/